# Why does my Eclipse different highlight rules to .xml and android's .xml?

Tags: android, eclipse

It's a normal .xml:[image]
and it's a android .xml:[image]

In normal .xml, eclipse adds a redundant highlight on my "color" tag.
I don't like this, but can't find where the configure is.

Comment: This picture is not proper, but expresses my problem. In later picture, even if I were to move the cursor to line 3, the "color" wouldn't be highlighted. This is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first XML file is being edited by the XML Editor built into Eclipse. The second is being edited by the Android Resource Editor. It just works differently. You can right-click on the file name in the Package Explorer and select which editor you want to use under Open With.